# Limits for floating point types?

Tags: c, types, floating-point, limit

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
 
int main(void){
        printf("Type                Size      Min                 Max\n----------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("%-20s%-10d%-20ld%-20ld\n", "long", sizeof(long), LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX);
        printf("%-20s%-10d%-20lu%-20lu\n", "unsigned long", sizeof(long), 0, ULONG_MAX);
        return 0;
}
```

where `double`? i.e. variable `LONG_MIN` be in file `limits.h`. in which type double?

```
   int i, min, max;

    for (i = 1.0; i > 0; ++i)
    {
        max = i;
    };
    min = i;
    printf ("int: min: %d max: %d \n", min, max);
```

How to do that for float and double? How is min calculated for this variable?
sorry bad english

Comment: You'll find valid printf formatting codes in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#Format_placeholders

Comment: I think he's asking where to find `DBL_MIN` and `DBL_MAX`. A good question, actually.

Comment: Even with multiple edits - **thx Juliet & all other** - this post is not clear !

Comment: Just to let you know, I don't think you should use `min` and `max`. Rename them to `imin` and `imax`. This is because of `#define min(a,b) = a>b ? b : a` somewhere out there... (not sure where.)

Comment: @ferz Because we can't understand it that well. Did you try using [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/)? (Of course, I didn't downvote *yet*, but others seem to have.)

Comment: @ferz:  Just rewrite your question to "Where are the limits for floating-point types defined?" and remove all of the irrelevant example code, and you'd be done.  Though I imagine there is a duplicate question already.  I changed the title for you; I am reluctant to change the content since you may in fact be asking something else entirely!

Comment: @Clifford sorry bad english. i'm be to write better try. however in file limits.h and float.h not variable dbl_min and  dbl_max and flt_max. i'm do task from book Kernighan, Brian W.; Dennis M. Ritchie task 2.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

on linux, I have float.h which has FLT_MAX and DBL_MAX defined for maximum float and double values respectively. I'm not sure how "standard" that is, though...

Comment: If we are to trust [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Float.h), standard enough. Be careful, however: `DBL_MIN` does not work the same way as `INT_MIN`.

Comment: It is entirely standard (in all of ANSI C89, ISO C90 and ISO C99)

Answer (score 17):

The limits for floating point types are defined in [float.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cfloat/) not limits.h

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you want:

float: %f

long float (double): %lf

You may also want to see it in exponential notation: %E

For min/max for float and double here is what you want

Here's a snippet from float.h:

```
#define DBL_MAX 1.7976931348623158e+308 /* max value */
#define DBL_MIN 2.2250738585072014e-308 /* min positive value */

#define FLT_MAX 3.402823466e+38F /* max value */
#define FLT_MIN 1.175494351e-38F /* min positive value */
```

Comment: He is looking for MIX and MAX constants for those types

Comment: `%f` takes a `double` argument.  (But if a `float` is passed via `...`, it automatically gets promoted to `double`.)  `%lf` is incorrect.  `%Lf` can be used for a `long double` argument.

Comment: Defining those values might be a good solution in embedded environments where "float.h" header doesn't always exist

Answer (score -3):

To compute the limits for a given data-type, you have to compute simply `(2^(sizeof(type) * 8)) - 1`, which is `(2^number_of_bits) - 1`.

Then, if you consider this type to be signed min and max values are `-2^(number_of_bits - 1)` and `(2^(number_of_bits - 1)) - 1` or if they're unsigned MIN will be 0 and MAX `(2^number_of_bits) - 1`.

This applies only to integer types, so not for floats and doubles, and then only for Two's Complement integer representations.

Comment: That won't work for floating point types which is what he is asking (albeit in a somewhat garbled fashion).  He already has the limits for integer types provided by limits.h

Comment: @Clifford: in fact I said it will work only for integers. I missed limiths.h anyway. ;)

Comment: You did indeed say that, my point was why?  It does not answer the question; merely makes a simple thing complicated.  Your formulae are not even correct, even if you did remember to multiply by CHAR_BIT in every case.

Comment: @clifford: I didn't noticed he included limits.h